# Data grid, Maximum call stack size exceeded ERROR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid

I'm trying to add buttons in two columns of the data grid (update & delete) but it's giving me this error.

I even deleted some columns too but no luck.

Is there any other way in which instead of deleting row by a button just delete it by selecting?

```js
 const columns =[
    { field: "id", headerName:"id" },
    { field:"fname", headerName:"First Name", flex:1, cellClassName:"name--column-cell"},
    { field:"Date of Joining", headerName:"DOJ", flex:1},
    { field:"phone", headerName:"Contact#", flex:1},
    { field:"Email", headerName:"Email", flex:1},
    { field:"depart", headerName:"Department", flex:1},
    { field:"desig", headerName:"Designation", flex:1},
    { field:"shift", headerName:"Shift", flex:1},
    { field:"salarymode", headerName:"Salary Mode", flex:1},
    { field:"", flex:1 , field: "Print",renderCell: (cellValues) => {  return (
    <Button
    variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={(event) => {
     handleClick(event, cellValues); }}>  
     Update  </Button>) }} ,
     { field:"", flex:1 , field: "Print",renderCell: (cellValues) => {  return (
      <Button
      variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={(event) => {
       handleClick(event, cellValues);
       }}>
      Delete
      </Button>)
    }}
    ]
```